# To view dropdownlist value in gridview (visual studio 2012)

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

i have two tables dbo.rank( rankID,rankName) and dbo.tbStaff (Staff ID, RankID, StaffName). And dropdownlist which diplays rankName. But in gridview it is showing rankID. How do I make it show rankName as in dropdownlist. Pls HELP!!!

Here is my dropdownlist code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="29px" style="margin-left: 53px" Width="422px" 
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="RankName" DataValueField="RankID">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectSPConnectionString %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT [RankID],[RankName] FROM [tbRank] ORDER BY [RankID]" 
ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectSPConnectionString.ProviderName %>">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And my gv:

Comment: dear can you shear your aspx code

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="29px" style="margin-left: 53px" Width="422px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="RankName" DataValueField="RankID">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectSPConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [RankID],[RankName] FROM [tbRank] ORDER BY [RankID]" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectSPConnectionString.ProviderName %>"></asp:SqlDataSource>

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="gvStaff" runat="server" Height="126px" Width="995px" BackColor="#6AB79A" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" >
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CCFFFF" />
                    </asp:GridView>

Comment: please shear your gridview code which have problem then we will help you better

Comment: Private Sub getStaff()

        Dim tblStaff As New DataTable
        connects()
        cmd.CommandText = "selectStaff"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sno", "")
        adp.Fill(tblStaff)
        conn.Close()

        gvStaff.DataSource = tblStaff
        gvStaff.DataBind()
    End Sub

Comment: where is your rank id in gridview is it label,bound field,template field

Comment: Add bound columns to your gridview and specify the columns for the DB to display. Also take out autogenerate columns.

Answer (score 0):

you have to customize your grid try this

```
        <asp:GridView ID="gvStaff" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns ="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("RankID") %>' runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("RankName") %>' runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: i only want to display rankName in gv....and the gv is populated with data from tbStaff which does not have rankName coloumn.But tbStaff (database table) have rankID. In my db, it also have tbRank table which have rankID and rankName...

Comment: do you have any relational key between tbStaff and tbRank, like

Comment: fi you have then use join in you query

Comment: do one thing show me your both table structure or send me you both table columns name

Comment: no. i am actually v v new to this, and m sorry if my explnation isnt good.

Comment: put this in your code cmd.CommandText= "Select tbRank.rankID, tbRank.RankName from tbStaff Inner Join tbRank on tbRank.rankID = tbStaff.rankID"

Comment: so your code will be like this  Private Sub getStaff() Dim tblStaff As New DataTable connects() cmd.CommandText = "Select tbRank.rankID, tbRank.RankName from tbStaff Inner Join tbRank on tbRank.rankID = tbStaff.rankID" cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sno", "") adp.Fill(tblStaff) conn.Close() gvStaff.DataSource = tblStaff gvStaff.DataBind() End Sub